# Objects removed from OWIN Environment dictionary after adding it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I working on MVC project compatible with OWIN Middleware pipeline.

In Action of the controller i want to store some objects for some reson inside the Environment object so i do some thing like that:

```
  Request.GetOwinContext().Environment["loginViewModel"] = model;
  Request.GetOwinContext().Environment["signInMessage"] = message;
```

When i try to get this keys from another controller's action i found that the Environment object is not contains this keys so what is the wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figure out the solution,

Environment object is related to the current request so each request has it's own environment, there are a standard OWIN Environment keys that should populate the Environment dictionary every time the request is coming and if i want to add to this environment request i should add this for each request for example using middleware. so i used session instead to store this objects.